# FirebaseImageLoader doesn't download image

Tags: firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm trying to download image from storage inside of ViewHolder, but it doesn't work:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference();
StorageReference imgRef = storageReference.child("11325404_436219506581300_875224883_a.jpg");
Glide.with(context)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(imgRef)
                .into(imageView);
```

When I use uri instead of FirebaseImageLoader everything works fine:

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView)
```

What could be a reason for that?

Update: I've tried to add this code and it shows me right links to images in storage

```
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(uri));
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });
```

Comment: A few questions:

  * What errors are you seeing?
  * What versions of firebase-ui-storage and firebase-storage are you using?

Comment: I don't see any errors. Versions are 1.2.0 and 10.2.4.
The only thisng mentioning firebase storage is this:

I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:1
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage, version >= 1

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue here, images were loading just fine last week but nothing this week :(

Comment: same here, also with old working version 0.6.0. 
Must be some kind of server issue