# Android Firebase UI image loading not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebaseui

I'm able to load images fro Firebase storage using this code:

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference().child("Users/" +userId +".jpg");
final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                Log.d(TAG, "downloadImageFromServer onSuccess: ");
                Glide.with(UserActivity.this).load(bitmap).asBitmap().into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_photo));
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "downloadImageFromServer onFailure() called with: exception = [" + exception + "]");
            }
        });
```

but not using this code:

```
final StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference().child("Users/" +userId +".jpg");
Glide.with(UserActivity.this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_photo));
```

Both are taken from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) and the second one seems much more convenient.

There seem to be no errors in the log.

Can someone please explain the difference?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829591/firebaseimageloader-doesnt-download-image) is the only other question I've fount on this topic but it has no answer.

I'm using `com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6` and `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0`

Comment: I've seen that a guy was having problem on the firebase-storage version. Can you try to downgrade it to 10.2.1 and check if it works then?

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0):

To load an image from Firebase storage using Glyde I used this method in my project. It works fine:

```
private void loadImage(){
        StorageReference storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        StorageReference userStorage = storage.child("Users").child(userID);

        userStorage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Glide.with(context).load(uri.toString()).into(profileImage);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // failed
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is basically the approach that OP mentioned that's working